# How to get Asterisks in the accno value from the table using cobol and db2

Tags: db2, cobol

If the type is "accno" then we have to fetch the value from the table as shown in result value - the account number should be first 6 digit as asterisk and last 4 digit as number using COBOL programing.

table

agent   type    account no
l1  name    jimmy
l2  accno   8257547429
l3  email   abc@gmail.com
result value

agent   type    account no
l1  name    jimmy
l2  accno   ******7429
l3  email   abc@gmail.com

I tried this query but it's not correct as it is sql query I want to use COBOL programming using move/if statements.
I am fetching the table to get the acc value and generating a report and the value in the report should be in asterisks form.

SELECT ACC_NO,
CONCAT('*****', RIGHT(pre_val, 4)) AS pre_val,
CONCAT('*****', RIGHT(new_val, 4)) AS new_val
FROM yourTable

Answer (score 0):

In pure COBOL code soemthing like:

```
03 ACCT-ALL-TEN.
   05 FIRST-SIX    PIC X(6).
   05 LAST-FOUR    PIC X(4).
.......
     MOVE ACCT-NO TO ACCT-ALL-TEN.
     MOVE '******' TO FIRST_SIX.
     DISPLAY ACCT-ALL-TEN.
```

Comment: Can you use cobol and db2

Comment: If you are using COBOL you have to use DB2 to get the data. So yes. DB2 has a pre-compiler that allows you to embed SQL statements in your COBOL code. Its fairly complex and you really need the manual before you start. However this s the most common setup on mainframe systems.

Comment: I am not using display statement and also "First_six" also not working can you suggest some other method.